# Yii2 Method is not allowed in testing with Codeception

Tags: yii2, codeception

I try to test my code with Codeception and my tests (both functional and acceptance) fails when I test logout option. They fails with "Method is not allowed (405)" because they are sent by GET method.
I have this code out of the box within the Nav widget:

```
$menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity['username'] . ')',
                                'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                                'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
```

This code works fine when I click the link by hand. In this case they are sent by POST method. 
But it doesn't work while testing.
Why does it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for logout you can add the form as follows, which will send the request using `POST`

```
$menuItems[] = '<li>'
        . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'], 'post')
        . Html::submitButton(
                'Logout ('.Yii::$app->user->identity['username'].')', ['class' => 'btn btn-link btnlogout']
        )
        . Html::endForm()
        . '</li>';
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! So in this case we should include this link in form tag.